# How to serve static web pages from a JSF application using Glassfish

Tags: jsf, glassfish-3

I have a JSF 2.0 application running under Glassfish 3.1.1 and I need to serve static web pages that are physically located apart from my application root that is created when my WAR file is deployed.  I've found various references (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636503/glassfish-vhost-to-serve-only-static-contents-disable-session-how-to) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266608/how-to-provide-access-to-an-external-resource-file-for-a-glassfish-web-applica)) to defining an alternate docroot using a tag such as

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/myimages/* dir=/images"/>
```

added to sun-web.xml (which I would presume means glassfish-web.xml in Glassfish 3.1.1).  I can't seem to get it to work, however.  In my case, I think the problem is that glassfish-web.xml simply isn't defining enough context for the alternate docroot to have any meaning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
  <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/myimages/* dir=/images"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

The meat of my application definition seems to be much more in web.xml than glassfish-web.xml.  Do I perhaps need to put something there instead to reference the alternate docroot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exact configuration requires a `/images/myimages` folder relative to the absolute root of the same disk as where the JVM of the webserver is running in. A file `foo.png` in that folder is then available by `http://localhost:8080/contextname/myimages/foo.png`.

A common confusion around this setting is that the `from` attribute is been interpreted as alone the context path in URL and not as an actual subfolder in the `dir` location. But this is thus not true.

If you're running Glassfish on a Windows environment then you need to specify the disk letter in the `dir` as well like so `dir=C:/images`.

Comment: Actually, under Windows it appears to search from the domain root unless you prefix the `dir=` value with `C:`.  However, even when I provide a valid path, I am getting an error: `SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener`.  So I guess this answers my configuration question.

Comment: Right. Windows is an odd beast. I've updated the answer. As to the new problem, does this exception disappear when you remove the alternate docroot?

Comment: The exception did not disappear when I removed the alternate docroot, so I put it back in, restarted Glassfish and all works well now.  An English description of the configuration might be helpful to some, which is:  For URIs that match the `from` pattern in the alternatedocroot property's `value` attribute, the actual file path accessed is equal to the value of the `dir` path plus the portion of the URI that follows the context/app name.

Comment: Oh, you just didn't restart Glassfish at all when you made changes in `glassfish-web.xml`?

Comment: No.  Glassfish picks up changes to `glassfish-web.xml` on the fly - even now I can change the `from` pattern, for instance, and it will update itself in a few moments.  It's not uncommon for a Glassfish instance to get out of sorts, however, especially when running in my development environment (NetBeans 7.0.1).  It may have even been my initial mucking around not knowing quite what I was doing that caused it to go off the rails.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the dir path in a way that both linux and windows understand it? We are developing in a team some on windows/some on linux.